# Autocomplete restrict results

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Reading the documentation of google maps, geocoding service, I see that to restrict the search results, for example in the country, I have to enter

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&components=country:IT&sensor=true
```

But it does not work!
If I type in "Via" returns results like:

[image: results]

I forget to do something?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
types: ['(cities)'],
componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Comment: I'm not using api of places, but the geocoding service.